# Sound stopped working on Debian

Tags: debian, audio, settings

I've been using debian 9 from sometime, it's been good. But suddenly audio has stopped working. I used headphones, and after that it has stopped working. It is showing popular "Dummy Output" for output devices in Sound Setting. I know there are many questions and answers available in this forum and others, but I'm not getting proper diagnosis of what has happened, and how to fix it. Some tests I ran -

```
pacmd list-cards
0 card(s) available.

aplay -L
default
      Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
      Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)

lspci -nnk | grep -A1 Audio
<< shows no output here>>

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
```

This is on my dell inspiron laptop. Some hardware specs:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -A4 'Base Board'
Base Board Information
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: 07JM0H
Version: A00

sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
Inspiron 5559


sudo dmidecode | grep -A4 'Audio'
External Reference Designator: Audio Jack
External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
   Internal Reference Designator: JSIM1
--
   Port Type: Audio Port

 Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
 Port Connector Information
 Internal Reference Designator: JXDP1 - CPU XDP Port
```

**UPDATE**
     I did diagnostic checks in BIOS. All other tests passed, except sound. When it said it played 6 tunes, I didn't hear anything, and it didn't show sound testing as passed. If sound testing is failed at BIOS level, what is the solution?

Comment: First, what's the make and model of the system - or if you've built it yourself, the make and model of the motherboard? Are you using USB headphones or analog ones? USB headphones bring their own sound device; analog ones use the system's built-in sound chip, or possibly a dedicated sound card if you have one.

Comment: It's a factory built dell inspiron laptop, and it was analog headphone.

Comment: There are so many models and versions of "Dell Inspiron" around that your description is not very useful. Please install the `dmidecode` package if it isn't already installed, and then run `dmidecode -s system-product-name` as root. The output of that command should allow for more exact identification.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Will provide all the information in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @telcoM I have added some information. Hope that is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If a BIOS-level diagnostic fails to produce any sound, it's most likely a hardware fault.

Looking at the [Dell Inspiron 5559 service manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15-5559-laptop_service%20manual_en-us.pdf), the fault might possibly be in the I/O board described on pages 53-54 of the service manual.

On the other hand, since the BIOS fails to detect the audio controller at all, the fault might also be within the actual system board.

Overall, if the laptop is still under warranty, now would be a great time to take advantage of it.

Comment: Hi. I checked BIOS settings. In "system information" -> Audio Controller was "none". And System configuration -> Audio -> Audio was enabled...

Comment: Updated based on the new information you added.

Comment: I don't know what happened, automagically sound is back. Just guessing  loose connection or something...I'm not going to use headphones though! Thanks for your support...